# SQL convert varchar2 to number

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this table X with only one column, BMI. All values are of datatype VARCHAR2(5 byte).

```
BMI
---
24.81
34.23
23.21
...
```

Question how to convert these values into number? I've tried

```
SELECT to_number(BMI) FROM X;
```

But i get the error 'invalid number', don't know why...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please add a relevant tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does sound like you are using an Oracle database (`varchar2` date type...)

If so, it looks like your session has an unexpected value for the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`  NLS parameter.

You can check what you currently have by querying

```
select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

On my database, it returns a value of `.,`, where that first character `.` represents what Oracle expects as the decimal character (The 2nd character, in this case the `,`, is used to determine the group separator character).  If your database returns a different set of 2 characters, then that would explain why it's unable to parse your values as numbers.

A couple of options:

Consider changing the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` NLS parameter for your session:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'; -- set '.' as the decimal character for this session.
```

After doing that, you should have no problem calling `TO_NUMBER` the way you tried already.

Alternatively, you can add additional parameters to the `TO_NUMBER` function call to force the correct decimal character for that call.  Something like this:

```
SELECT to_number(BMI, '99D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') FROM X;
```

**Relevant documentation references**

- [TO_NUMBER Function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions226.htm)
- [Number Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i34570)
- [NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG218)

Comment: Yes, indeed on my database it was returning ,. which was the opposite of ., thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using ORACLE PL/SQL.

I am using

```
BANNER
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Try this:

```
SELECT   TO_NUMBER(REPLACE (
                      REPLACE (BMI,
                               ',',
                               (SELECT   SUBSTR (VALUE, 1, 1)
                                  FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                                 WHERE   PARAMETER = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS')),
                      '.',
                      (SELECT   SUBSTR (VALUE, 1, 1)
                         FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                        WHERE   PARAMETER = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS')
                   ))
            MY_NUMBER_CONVERTED
  FROM   X;
```